# lcov mis-interpretation of directories

Tags: lcov

I'm developing a software project with source code spread across different directories, some parts being project-specific, other parts are shared across projects.

I want to measure the test coverage for all source code in question, however, I fail to use the directory parameters for lcov correctly.

example:
the following files exist:

- `$HOME/dev/common/src/tools.cpp`
- `$HOME/dev/project/src/project.cpp`

the test executable is stored in `$HOME/dev/project/src/bin/unittest`

The makefile is executed from `$HOME/dev/project/src`

I invoke lcov as

```
        lcov --base-directory ../../ --directory ../../ --zerocounters -q
        ${MAKE} test
        lcov --base-directory ../../ --directory ../../ -c -o $(BINDIR)/unittests.info
```

I'd expect lcov to store the data as `/home/$USER/project/src/common/tools.cpp`

But then, I see output like
`SF:/home/$USER/project/tools.cpp`
Therefore, genhtml fails to find the sources, and cannot produce any output.

All *.gcda and *.gcno are stored next to the cpp files.

I'd rather not change directories before executing commands, as all of this is executed in a makefile

What am I missing?

Cheers,
Michael